# How to detect problem type in cvxpy framework?

Tags: optimization, cvxpy

We have a optimization problem formulated in Cvxpy framework.

We want to detect its problem type.

The standard problem types are: (MI)LP, (MI)QP, (MI)QCQP, (MI)SOCP, (MI)NLP.

How to best achieve this in cvxpy?

Comment: Imho cvxpy doesn't really think in the (less modern) classification. cvxpy is only interested in conic optimization problems and this classification differs a lot from yours (and NLPs are not supported at all). You can [ask](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.problems.html#cvxpy.problems.problem.Problem.is_qp) if it's a C(onvex) QP, but other inferences might be a bit harder to obtain. See [docs: Reductions](https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.reductions.html#reductions-api)

Comment: How did you conclude **"cvxpy is only interested in conic optimization problems"**, since it supports: (MI)LP, (MI)QP, (MI)QCQP, (MI)SOCP?

Comment: Yes, QP can indeed be detected from `is_qp()`. How would **Reductions** help me?